# Unable to make Flask-SQLAlchemy connect to my Google App Engine DB

Tags: google-app-engine, web, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to set up a web-application based on Flask using Google App Engine (I'm new to both).
The web-application receives data from the client and it should be processed and saved in a database.

I've tried to use Flask-SQLAlchemy but I'm unable to set it up with Google Cloud SQL, I've used [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/create-instance#create-2nd-gen) to create a MySQL DB in the same project:

[image: DB on GAE]

and then I'm trying to use it on my main python code:

```
app.config('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI') = 'mysql+mysqldb://root@/Results?unix_socket=/cloudsql/crafty-circlet-164415:psy01'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'NglfxE8FOP9pgV8fxpyj'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Result(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    profession = db.Column(db.Text)
    year = db.Column(db.Text)
    pressure_level = db.Column(db.Integer)
    reported_suc_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    marked_suc_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    real_suc_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    insertion_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, name, profession, year, pressure_level, reported_suc_count, marked_suc_count, real_suc_count):
        self.name = name
        self.profession = profession
        self.year = year
        self.pressure_level = pressure_level
        self.reported_suc_count = reported_suc_count
        self.marked_suc_count = marked_suc_count
        self.real_suc_count = real_suc_count
        self.insertion_time = datetime.utcnow()

@app.route('/resultform', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def resultform():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['successmatrices']:
            flash('please fill all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            if 'name' in request.form:
                name = request.form['name']
            else:
                name = None
            if 'profession' in request.form:
                profession = request.form['profession']
            else:
                profession = None
            if 'year' in request.form:
                year = request.form['year']
            else:
                year = None
            if 'pressure_level' in request.form:
                pressure_level = int(request.form['pressure_level'])
            else:
                pressure_level = None
            if 'successmatrices' in request.form:
                successmatrices = int(request.form['successmatrices'])
            else:
                successmatrices = 0
            new_result = Result(name=name, profession=profession, year=year, pressure_level=pressure_level, reported_suc_count=successmatrices, marked_suc_count=len(session['marked']), real_suc_count=len(session['correct']))
            db.session.add(new_result)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('showresults'))
    return render_template("resultform.html")

@app.route('/showresults')
def showresults():
    return render_template("showresults.html", results=Results.query.all())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I'm trying to run it in my local development (I'm using PyCharm) I receive the following error in the background:

```
ERROR    2017-04-16 09:20:19,802 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\<>\PycharmProjects\crafty-circlet-164415\main.py", line 7
    app.config('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI') = 'mysql+mysqldb://root@/Results?unix_socket=/cloudsql/crafty-circlet-164415:psy01'
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

And after deployment to GAE the following error appears:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: and also you have to include cloud sql instance name under beta settings app.yaml file (flex env).

Answer (score 3):

[`app.config`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.config) is a dictionary, so to add a config value you'll use a `[ ]` instead of `()` just as done in you `app.config['SECRET_KEY']`.

So it should be:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

Some other pointers too for a successful connection. You'll need to format your connection details properly:

```
USER = 'root'
PASSWORD = 'your-cloudsql-password'
DATABASE = 'your-cloudsql-database-name'
# connection_name is of the format `project:region:your-cloudsql-instance`
CONNECTION_NAME = 'your-cloudsql-connection-name' 

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{database}'
    '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{connection_name}').format(
        user=USER, password=PASSWORD,
        database=DATABASE, connection_name=CONNECTION_NAME)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =  SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

*I'll probably separate my secrets and all other sensitive info into a config file not checked into source or use environment variables, etc.*

If you want to locally test your application with your Cloud SQL instance, you'll need to install [the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/#configure-local-env) and add the connection name as an environment variable and the `MySQLdb` library to your `app.yaml`

```
> cloud_sql_proxy -instances=your-connection-name=tcp:3306
```

Else you can use a local MySQL instance for testing but switching to Cloud SQL when on app engine.

[More information on setting up Cloud SQL with App Engine can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/cloud-sql/#setting-up)